# Base template doesn't render other regions by default when calling this.render('template')

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Been stuck on this for a few hours...I'm having a weird behaviour when using iron:router (1.0.1) and trying to render a 403 access forbidden template inside my base template:

I have a default template set using iron-router default options like this

```
Router.configure({
      layoutTemplate: 'basicLayout',
      yieldRegions: {
        'header': {to: 'header'},
        'footer': {to: 'footer'}
      }
    });

Router.plugin('dataNotFound', {notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'});
```

Here it is my template:

```
<template name="basicLayout">
    <header>
        {{> yield 'header'}}
    </header>
    <div id="main">
        {{> yield}}
    </div>
    <footer class="sticky-footer">
        {{> yield 'footer'}}
    </footer>
</template>
```

Everything works as expected and I'm able to render individual templates inside this layout by defining routes in the normal way:

```
Router.route('ordersList', {
    path: '/orders',
    template: 'ordersList',
    waitOn: function () {
        Meteor.subscribe('Orders');
    }
});
```

However, when I do:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {

        if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), ['delivery'])) {
            this.next();
        } else {
            this.render('accessDenied');
        }
    }
    , {
        only: 'ordersList'
    });
```

It only renders the template in the main region, but no header or footer are rendered (they are there, but empty).

If I force the rendering for the regions, using

```
this.renderRegions();
this.render('accessDenied');
```

Everything works as expected, however this seems a little bit weird -and redundant- usage to me, it should just be enough without calling `this.renderRegions()`. Is this a bug or a feature? Or is there anything I'm doing wrong? I saw many examples that just use `this.render('templateName')`

Comment: What about specifying an `accessDenied` route, and in your onBeforeAction calling `this.redirect` instead of `this.render`? I know that doesn't answer your question, but I'm just wondering if that will work?

Comment: @Scotty That works perfectly, as it is the way I use for other parts of the app: Declaring a route and setting: `template: 'accessDenied'`  (or whatever other template it is)

Comment: For the dataNotFound plugin, I see [they call renderRegions explicitly](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/648bed25948e1a019fb27e534e50c8c972694845/lib/hooks.js#L52), so that's probably how it was designed.